# How can I replace special characters by column value in every row in excel?

Tags: excel, replace

I need to replace (～) this special character by first column value in same as every rows. But I don't know how to write a formula for this. I attached my excel file image link, please see the image then it will be easy to understand exactly what I want to do. If anyone can solve this problem I'll be glad of him.

[image: click here to view the example image file]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter the below formula in cell `G1` and drag it down,

```
=SUBSTITUTE(F1,"~",A1)
```